# failed opening required in laravel warning and fatal error

Tags: php, laravel

laravel giving error  failed opening required thrn (file path)(include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')in (file path)

```
//my index file code id shown below


//require __DIR__.'public/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'public/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

//$app = require_once __DIR__.'/public/bootstrap/app.php';
$app = require_once (realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'/public/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: Here's another idea: Why not switch 

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/public/bootstrap/app.php';
//$app = require_once (realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'/public/bootstrap/app.php';`

Comment: i didi it but error still exist

Answer (score 10):

If this is a new installation, you need to run `composer install`.

If it's an existing installation (vendor folder exists) run `composer update`.

Comment: Warning: require_once(C:\Users\zumos\Desktop\ecom2\core\publicecom2/public/core/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\zumos\Desktop\ecom2\core\public\index.php on line 25

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\zumos\Desktop\ecom2\core\publicecom2/public/core/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\zumos\Desktop\ecom2\core\public\index.php on line 25

Comment: This doesn't work on OneDrive, anyway thank you for helping.

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1:**
Run: Composer Install for new Installation.

Run: Composer Update for Existing Installation.

**Step 2:** Make .env file

**Step 3:** Run: Php artisan migrate (Make database )

**Step 4:** Run: Php artisan key:generate

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly on server, just to add, you need SSH access for server.

Comment: This doesn't work on OneDrive, it returns an error exception 
 [ErrorException] on finding the directory proc_open(NUL).

Anyway, thank you Amrullah Hashimi!

Comment: Thank you Amrullah this works on Windows 10, using Wnmp,by enabling the extension=fileinfo on C:\Wnmp\php directory,